# Backup on NAS - The network is busy ERROR

Tags: networking, backup, nas, qnap

We have a backup system in our company, those backups go to 3 different locations. For some reason one location called "Hades" has an error sometimes.

I would be happy if anybody knows what could be the problem

> Error while backuping (name of the program that we want to make a backup for) on Qnap Hades: System.IO.IOException: The network is busy. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) at ERPBackUp.Program.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1()

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states there is a network error and that can always happen.
The only option usually is to retry it again after some time.

Another reason might be that it's just the QNAP server which is not answering, i.e. because it's busy with some stuff. Then the problem might be that the server should get the running software reduced, down to the important things. I know QNAP offers a bunch of things to run on the servers and that can even be increased by some software packages. In this case it might be advisable to uninstall some things.
Also increasing the swap partition and increasing memory might help.